# ubuntu resize partition after installing

Tags: 12.04, boot, partitioning, gparted

AS I have been trying to resize my partition of hardisk.I have total volume of 500Gb as Master.I am not sure in this and I need you'r suggestion how to achieve it.

[image]

Note: And I  don't want to lose anything too.

Answer (score 2):

- You installed Ubuntu on a 500 GB partition.To resize that partition,you need to boot ubuntu live disk.
- After booting ubuntu live disk,open gparted.
- Right-click on the 500 GB partition and then resize it.
- After resizing an unallocated space was created.
- Create a new ntfs or ext4 partition(*whatever you want*) from that unallocated space.

By doing the above,you doesn't loose any datas.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your CD/USB that contains the Ubuntu live cd, then go to the utility called gparted and change the partition as you like from there, you can also use Parted Magic and burn it to a CD/USB but you now have to pay for it and the version you can find its quite old although it works perfectly for me.

Hope it helped.